# Variance of the influence function of the parameters of an over-dispersed poisson model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, overdispersion

Assume an over-dispersed Poisson model:
\begin{align}
E[C_ij] &= m_ij \quad\text{ and }  \\
{\rm Var}[C_ij] &= ∅E[C_ij]= ∅m_ij  \\
\log(m_{ij}) &= n_ij  \\
n_{ij} &= c+ α_i + β_j \quad\text{ and }  \\
α_1 &= β_1 = 0
\end{align}
$C_{ij}$ is is the estimate to be modeled and $α_i$ and $β_j$ are row and column parameters respectively.

Denote $IF(x;α_i;F_∅)$ the influence function of a large value of $x$ on $α_i$.

What I want to know is how $V(α_i, F_∅) = E(IF(x;α_i;F_∅) IF(x;α_i;F_∅)')$ can be estimated? (Note that $IF(x;α_i;F_∅)'$ stands for the transposed influence function and $V$ for the asymptotic variance)

Comment: This reads somewhat like bookwork. Is this a question from some subject or course?

Comment: Yes, it is related to my course on robust statistics. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "I want to know how <...> is?", it's not completely clear what you're asking (it's not grammatical English and the intended meaning is ambiguous - there are a number of things that might mean). Can you please clarify?

Comment: I appoligize for my poor English. What I need to know is how the assymptotic variance of $α_i$ ($V(α_i, F_∅$) can be estimated. So I need a mathematical formula. I am given the over-dispersed poisson model and I know that  $V(α_i, F_∅) = E(IF(x;α_i;F_∅) IF(x;α_i;F_∅)')$. Further, you can also assume that I know the formula of the influence function $IF(x;α_i;F_∅)$, but this is to complex to type down (but I do not know how to calculate its expected value). I have no clue on how to start on this, so it can also be possible that more information is needed first. Any information is welcome.

Comment: Editted. Hope someone can help.